# How can I get Jenkins to use the jar included in source control rather than the jar in the ant/lib folder?

Tags: jenkins, ant, hudson

I have a jar file to build my project stored within source control with the rest of the project files.  An older version of this jar file is in the ant/lib/ folder as well.  When I do a Jenkins deployment, it is referencing the old jar despite being aware of the jar in source control.  How can I get Jenkins to use the file in source control rather than in the ant/lib/ folder?

Comment: You could try and explicitly specify the classpath in the taskdef statement, but I suspect because jars in the antlib will be added to classpath when ANT starts, these will be used. Certainly worth a try. Recommend purging the $ANT_HOME/lib and $HOME/.ant/lib directories and remove environmental dependencies

Comment: For extra credit use Apache ivy to manage all your builds external dependencies, including jars used for ANT tasks

Comment: I do not have access to the server where Jenkins and Ant run.  I can go through the process of trying to get the file updated or removed but it could take days.

Comment: Not an uncommon problem.... I have seen this repeatedly in corporate build environments. Poor isolation between multiple tenants, often unnoticed .... Not a good place to be.... Try explicitly setting the classpath on the taskdef and hope for the best. A really crazy idea would be to containerize your build, but of course that would need Jenkins server support too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the classpath is already set to the file I want it to use.  The -verbose output shows that ant finds the correct jar but ends up using the wrong one.

Comment: I ended up getting the Jar deleted from the server. Didn't take as long as I had expected.